# SQL Server query is taking 3 min 40 Sec. How to improve the execution Time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlperformance

I have a query that is taking 3 min 40 sec.

Here except the `AirESet` and `ELT_B` tables, all other tables are lookup tables and there is a lot less data in these tables. Interestingly without these lookup tables execution time was around 30 sec. My understanding is with lookup tables containing a lot less data, performance should not degrade.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    RPGM.GroupID as RegionPerilGroupID,
    RPGM.GroupName as RPGroupName,
    LLGM.GroupID as LossLevelGroupID,
    LLG.GroupName As LLGroupName
FROM
    Acc.dbo.AIRESet ES 
JOIN 
    Acc.dbo.vw_RegionPerilGroup RPGM ON ES.RegionperilID = RPGM.RegionperilID 
                                     AND ModelLossFileID = 65 -- Line of Business
JOIN 
    AR.LA.ELT_B ELT WITH (NOLOCK) ON ES.EventNum = ELT.EventNum 
                                  AND ELT.Versionid = 215 
JOIN 
    AR.LA.LossLevelGroupMappings LLGM ON ELT.LossLevelID = LLGM. LossLevelID 
JOIN 
    AR.LA.LossLevelGroup LLG ON LLGM.GroupID = LLG.GroupID 
                             AND LLG.LosstypeId = 3 
JOIN 
    AR.LA.ReportMap RM ON RPGM.GroupId = RM.RegionPerilGroupID 
                       AND LLGM.GroupID = RM.LossLevelGroupID
JOIN 
    AR.LA.ReportMapFilterMappings RMFM ON RM.ReportMapID = RMFM.ReportMapID
                                       AND RMFM.FilterID = 15
ORDER BY 
    LossLevelGroupID, RegionPerilGroupID
```

Comment: Be sure that you have indexes on all the columns used for `JOIN`.

Comment: Show `vw_RegionPerilGroup`, that's a view not a table

Comment: Have you tried using query analyzer to narrow down where your problem(s) is happening?

Comment: @Lee: that won't make a difference.

Comment: Generally speaking, performance should not degrade when adding simple lookups. However, as you add complexity and joins, the server may create less optimal plans based on other server load and statistics, which may or may not be up-to-date. If you remove the joins, how many records are returned? It could be that the joins are excluding a number of records from `AIRESet`, which could decrease query performance.

Comment: @lee, will that really improve performance with SQL Server?

Comment: @Lee `GROUP BY` would also have to do a `SORT` and a aggregate operation, which is what `DISTINCT` does too.

Comment: The main thing you will want to do is, as @GordonLinoff mentioned, verify that any `JOIN`s you are performing are using indexed columns. Once you verify that, I would still use Query Analyzer to determine if there are any other places that you can improve on.

Comment: Show us the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

Let me take a guess.
Please add `option (HASH JOIN)` to your query.

---

P.s.
`SELECT distinct ...` is usually an indication for query logic issues.
Please find the cause for the duplications.

---

... and -

1. **No.

   You don't need indexes for equality join operations.**
   This is SQL Server, not MySQL and it supports HASH JOIN.

   Furthermore -
   **The use of indexes for retrieval of large data volumes leads to significant degradation in performance.**

---

2. **No.

   GROUP BY / DISTINCT does not necessarily imply a SORT operation.**
   It can be also implemented using HASH with complexity of O(1) instead of O(n*log n).

---

## The limitations of statistics

```
select @@version
```

---

> ```
> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64) 
>   Jun  9 2015 12:06:16 
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>   Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
> ```

---

```
create table t (n int primary key)

;with   t (n) as (select 1 union all select n+1 from t where n < 1000)
insert into dbo.t select n from t option  (maxrecursion 0)

create statistics t_n on t (n)
update statistics t (t_n)
```

---

```
;with x as (select * from t where sqrt(n) = n)
select * from x x0,x x1,x x2,x x3,x x4,x x5
```

---

> ```
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | n | n | n | n | n | n |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> ```

---

[image]

## HASH JOIN Vs. LOOP JOIN

```
create table t (i int,j1 int,j2 int,j3 int,j4 int,j5 int)

;with   t (n) as (select 0 union all select n+1 from t where n < 999)
insert into dbo.t (i,j1,j2,j3,j4,j5) 
select      1+t0.n+1000*t1.n,1+t0.n,1+t0.n,1+t0.n,1+t0.n,1+t0.n
from        t t0,t t1 
option      (maxrecursion 0)

create table d1 (j int primary key,k int)
create table d2 (j int primary key,k int)
create table d3 (j int primary key,k int)
create table d4 (j int primary key,k int)
create table d5 (j int primary key,k int)

;with   t (n) as (select 0 union all select n+1 from t where n < 999)
insert into dbo.d1 (j,k) 
select      1+t0.n,1
from        t t0 
option      (maxrecursion 0)

insert into d2 select * from d1
insert into d3 select * from d1
insert into d4 select * from d1
insert into d5 select * from d1
```

---

```
select  sum (d1.k+d2.k+d3.k+d4.k+d5.k)

from            t 
        join    d1 on t.j1 = d1.j 
        join    d2 on t.j2 = d2.j 
        join    d3 on t.j3 = d3.j 
        join    d4 on t.j4 = d4.j 
        join    d5 on t.j5 = d5.j 

option (hash join)
```

---

```
select  sum (d1.k+d2.k+d3.k+d4.k+d5.k)

from            t 
        join    d1 on t.j1 = d1.j 
        join    d2 on t.j2 = d2.j 
        join    d3 on t.j3 = d3.j 
        join    d4 on t.j4 = d4.j 
        join    d5 on t.j5 = d5.j 

option (loop join)
```

## HASH GROUP Vs. ORDER GROUP

```
create table t (i int,j int)

;with   t (n) as (select 0 union all select n+1 from t where n < 9)
insert into dbo.t (i,j) 
select      t0.n,t0.n
from        t t0,t t1,t t2,t t3,t t4,t t5,t t6
```

---

```
select      distinct
            i,j
from        t
option      (HASH GROUP)
;

select      i,j
from        t
group by    i,j
option      (HASH GROUP)
;
```

---

```
select      distinct
            i,j
from        t
option      (ORDER GROUP)
;

select      i,j
from        t
group by    i,j
option      (ORDER GROUP)
;
```

Comment: This is  an interesting answer. There is one crucial thing missing from the question (the proposed query plan). It would be very interesting to see if Dudu's suggestion helped.

Comment: @Ritha, Have you collected statistics on the tables? It determines the HASH size.

Comment: @Ritha, also please add the 3 execution plans, without dim tables,with dim tables and with  `option (HASH JOIN)`

Comment: It would be very relevant to know which version of SQL Server this is being run on. Microsoft discourages the use of hints with versions of SQL Server post 2008.  If this type of hint helps with 2012 this would mean to me that the query engine is not as good as MS claims.

Comment: You really do not want to use hash joins for reference tables.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits, statistics are only statistics. Check my edited answer for a small demonstration.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits, changed my use-case a little bit, in order to make it more interesting

Comment: @GordonLinoff, please, go on

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . The main table would need to be hashed multiple times, once for each reference table.  That is much wasted effort.  Index lookups are much faster.

Comment: I am missing something here. If the user reruns this query using a hash join doesn't SQL Server have to rehash all the rows to build a hash table? Wouldn't it be better to use an existing index (btree) which may take a little longer to get to the value but does not have to be rebuilt? The only time I would prefer a hash join is if I am looking up many values in a query that I run rarely.

Comment: This is my SQL Server Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) 
 Apr 20 2015 17:29:27 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, please support your claim with an example. In the meantime check my example (see edited answer) that shows the opposite.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits, you hash the dimension tables and then streams the fact table - complexity O(n).

Comment: When you have a good hash its one read points to the associated bucket (O(n)). My comment is that in SQL Server you have to rebuild the entire hash table every time the join takes place.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits sorry but I don't get you.

Comment: Every time do a hash join SQL Server has to rebuild, from scratch, a hash table. That takes time.

Comment: Every time SQL Server does a hash join SQL Server has to rebuild, from scratch, a hash table. That takes time.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits, take a look at my example. How much time do you think it takes to build the hash tables for 5 tables with 1K rows each? Once this is done you are streaming the big table and working against the hash tables with O(1).

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, I invite you to tests the examples I've added for HASH GROUP Vs. ORDER GROUP.